# How to encode matrices uniquely

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computer-science

Given a square matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$, an operation $swap(A, i, j)$ is defined to swap row $i$ and $j$ of $A$ and do the same thing with the corresponding columns. For example, in the following example, we can see the $swap(A, 1, 3)$:

$$A=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \end{array} \right] ~~~~~\Rightarrow~~~~~ swap(A,1,3)=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
i & h & g \\
f & e & d \\
c & b & a \end{array} \right]$$

For a matrix $A$, let $swap^k(A)$ be the set of matrices produced by exactly $k$ swaps.  For example $B \in swap^3(A)$ means that there is a sequence of 3 swaps that can convert $A$ into $B$.

A **unique encoding** $\phi$ of this matrix is a function of $A$ such that:

$$\phi(A)=\phi(B) ~~~~ \Leftrightarrow ~~~~ \exists k ~:~ B \in swap^k(A)$$

For simplicity, we can assume that the matrix is symetric and its elements are in $\{0,1\}$. I am interested to know whether there exist such encoding for this case of matrices or if there is a proof for its non-existence.

**Edit.** What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you want a $\phi$ for every $k$? Or do you want a $\phi$ such that $\phi(A) = \phi(B) \Rightarrow B\in swap^k(A)$ for some $k$?

Comment: @WardBeullens $k$ is at most $n!$. I want $\phi$ to work for every matrix and possible $k$. (The matrix is symmetric 0/1)

Comment: It is impossible for one $\phi$ to work for every k. Assume such a $\phi$ exists then it should work for $k=0$ so this means that $\phi(A)=A$, but clearly this $\phi$ doesn't work for $k =1$

Comment: @WardBeullens The solution by DanielV proves the existence of such encoding.

Comment: The solution of DanielV doesn't work for any finite k. It corresponds to the second option in my first comment. I fear that first comment might not be clear enough?

Comment: @WardBeullens Double check my edit to make sure that the $\exists k$ is what you intended.

Comment: That, clears it up. In this way the solution of DanielV is a valid one, though not verry efficient.

Comment: What is the codomain of $\phi$?

Comment: @mvw It can be integers, or rationals or any other countable set.

Comment: @emab Are you sure that you want such a restricted swap function?  With your definition you can't arbitrarily swap two elements with each other in 1 step.

Comment: @DanielV The swap is the crucial part, otherwise the coding of a matrix wouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: For 0-1-matrices, $phi(A) = \phi(B)$ is just graph-isomorphism. So we should not expect $\phi$ to be computable in polynomial time.

Answer (score 5):

Such an encoding exists and is finite.  Whether or not it is tractable is a much harder question.

$\phi(A)$ can be defined to be an encoding of the span of the swaps of $A$:

$$\text{SwapSpan}(A) = \cup_{k=0}^{\infty} \text{swap}^k(A)$$
$$\phi(A) = \text{Encoding}(\text{SwapSpan}(A))$$

Since there are $n^2$ elements of the matrix, there is an upper bound of $(n^2)!$ number of matrices in $\text{SwapSpan}(A)$.  Explicitly writing out the list of matrices in lexicographical order is a valid canonical $\text{Encoding}$.

Note that if $A \in \text{SwapSpan}(B)$ then $\text{SwapSpan}(A) = \text{SwapSpan}(B)$ since the order of the swaps can simply be reversed.

The span can also be computed, since a breadth first search of all the swaps is guaranteed to terminate.

Whether or not this is tractable depends on your computing power and the size of your matrices.

Comment: The question asks for the existence of such encoding and your solution is correct, but I am looking for a more efficient way to do so.

Comment: @emab You improve the space efficiency by computing the $SwapSpan$ and only encoding the lexicographically first matrix in that list of matrices.  Thus $\phi$ can be reduced to a function of the form $\text{Matrix}^{n \times n} \to \text{Matrix}^{n \times n}$.  This strongly suggests that there is a much more efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of finding a canonical form for ${0,1}$ symmetric square matrices using simultaneous row and column swaps is one of the approaches for solving the [Graph Isomorphism Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) via [graph canonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization).  There are algorithms that do this is polynomial average time, the [best $O$-complexity algorithm](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25667/fastest-known-deterministic-algorithm-for-the-undirected-graph-isomorphism-probl) is still superpolynomial.  So, step 1 is to canonize your matrix/graph.

From here, you may compress the data to make it space efficient.  If your elements were in ${0,1}$, then you could make a binary blob, listing the rows in order.  If you had very few $1$'s (or $0$'s, really), you could store it as a sparse matrix (linked list of elements and their positions in each row).  Or, if you have some infinitesimal amount of tolerance for error, you could take your current encoding and send it through a hashing algorithm (like MD5).  Then, equality of the hash values indicates equality of the original matrices (modulo row swaps) with high probability.  This comparison would happen in constant time.

Comment: +1, it is so obvious when you read it in someone else's answer >_<

Comment: Oh nevermind, swapping rows changing the lexicographical order, this won't work so directly.

Comment: The compression is a good idea, but we also have column swap which is very important.

Comment: righto, edited to take that into account.  Unfortunately, adding columns swaps makes it alot harder to compute.

Answer (score 2):

You can encode rows and columns with multisymmetric functions (one set of generators for the rows, and one set of generators for the columns). [This paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/BAG/vol.40/no.1/b40h1dal.ps.gz) is quite a good source.

For example, a 2-by-2 matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ can be encoded as
$$
(ad, a+d, bc, b+c).
$$
This is by no means the most efficient encoding, but it should do the job.

[I made an edit because I just realize I misunderstood the problem.]